# How to trim emails in a column and at the same time remove duplicates (MSQL2017, UPDATE column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, sql-server-2017

I have a table with some data one of them are Emails that are stored in column called "Domain".

I would need to update "Domain" so I cut the emails and only leave domains (Example: `test@testmail.com` that would after query be like this `testmail.com`).

So the `Domain` column has over 290000 emails stored inside and there are also some NULL's...
As I said I am looking for domains and I don't need data left of and including `@`
Also don't need duplicated domain list or `NULL` values in `Domain` column.

So what I am looking for is a query that will trim the emails to transform them into domains at the same time the query would remove the data with `NULL` value and duplicated domains.

The final result should be column `Domain` with only unique domains and without NULLs inside.

Comment: What do you mean by "updating" and having distinct results at the same time ? Are you wishing to show the result or to update the table content ?

Comment: I want to update the table content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) AS email_domain
FROM table
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want unique domains . . .

```
select distinct (case when domain like '%@%'
                      then stuff(domain, 1, charindex('@', domain) + 1, '')
                      else domain
                 end)
from t
where domain is not null;
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to update the table content ?? This is just showing data

Comment: "what I am looking for is a query that will trim the emails to transform them into domains at the same time the query would remove the data with NULL value and duplicated domains."  If you want to change the table contents, I would suggest that you ask another question along with sample data and desired results.